# Facebook app beginners guide

Tags: facebook

I'm looking to write a facebook app that can hold some state. Basically what I want is something where using this app the user can issue questions to their friends (sort of like a survey but more complex interface). I have never written a facebook app so looking for a good place to start reading. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://gathadams.com/2007/06/18/how-to-write-a-facebook-application-in-10-minutes/) might help,. just google :)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I looked at few Google results including the one mentioned in this answer but they didn't seem very helpful because I was looking for some insight into building an app that can store some state in a backend and access it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you have never written the **"Facebook App"** before. Here are some key points which will help you to create your "First Facebook App".

Here are the steps which you need to follow : -

1. Login to "http://developers.facebook.com"
2. Create a "Facebook App" as per your need platform e.g android, ios, www
3. Select the catergory for "Facebook App"
4. Once your complete above three steps you will have **"APP ID"** and **"APP SECRET"** created for your **"Facebook App"**.
5. You need to create the **"Access Token"** using the **"Access Token Tool"** available on "http://developers.facebook.com"

Here are the articles which will guide you through the steps : -

1. **Build your own facebook app : -** http://techpost360.blogspot.com/2016/10/build-your-own-facebook-app.html
2. **Create Facebook Access Token : -** http://techpost360.blogspot.com/2016/10/create-facebook-access-token.html

One you are through with all the above steps than you are good to go with your own implementation of Facebook App.

Hope it will help you to start.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you will need to sign you app into the Facebook Developers website: http://developers.facebook.com. 
Here is a nice video I used to integrate the Facebook login into an android app. Although it is in Spanish, there is English subtitles that explain the concept.
Good luck!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jims30XAzjI&list=PLXvO8Pi6OUCZ-u5VG3JqyturXEcd3DI2s